# .newRichTextValue() not currently working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google form for a list of interviews that people have done. I want to have a specific sheet for pulling up a person by their ID and having all of their interviews pop up. People can have multiple interviews so I built a function that would look at every entry and return all of the interviews corresponding to their ID. Right now it works but it's hard to read. I want to bold only the questions.

I tried a couple of different methods. I stumbled across a similar question asked two years ago but since then google has come out with a way to bold only certain ranges of text using google scripts called newRichTextValue(). However I cant get that to work. It shows this message: com.google.apps.maestro.server.beans.trix.impl.RichTextValueApiAdapter@57995aa instead of what I want. I looked into it a little bit and this is supposed to be something that happens if you try to use RichTextValue in Gmail since it requires HTML.

```
function interview(alpha) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var interview = ss.getSheetByName("2020 Interview");
  var data = interview.getDataRange().getValues();
  var intvw = "";
  var bold = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setBold(true).build();
  var space = "\n\n";
  var difspace = "\n";
  var newtext;
  var month = ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", 'JUN', "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"];
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][0] == alpha){
      intvw = intvw + data[i][4] + " | " + data[i][1].getDate() + " " + month[data[i][1].getMonth()] + " " + data[i][1].getYear();
      intvw = intvw + space;
      newtext = data[0][5];
      newtext = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
                              .setText(newtext)
                              .setTextStyle(bold)
                              .build();
      intvw = intvw + newtext + difspace;
      intvw = intvw + data[i][5] + space;
  }
  }
  return intvw;
}
```

The output is currently:

Name | 1 MAY 2019

com.google.apps.maestro.server.beans.trix.impl.RichTextValueApiAdapter@579955aa

Their answer to the question

It should be:

Name | 1 MAY 2019

**The Question**

Their answer to the question

Comment: Since you're returning the output, I'm not sure what you're doing with the output. However, I think you'll need to use [.setRichTextValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setrichtextvaluevalue) or perhaps [.getText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value#getText())

Comment: This is a function that I can input into google sheets. So if I input "=interview(alpha)" into a cell, every question and answer that was asked will be input into the cell . It looks like .setRichTextValue() works by setting whatever range is selected as the RichTextValues. I might be able to do this if I set my range as the active cell and then keep track of the length of the questions and answers to try to determine what range to bold. I'll try this and see if it works out.

Comment: .setRichTextValue() doesn't work because custom functions only allow for return. I do not have "Permission" to use .setRichTextValue().

Comment: It would be helpful to see an example spreadsheet.  Other wise we can't reproduce output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `newRichTextValue().build();`does not quite work in the way you would like to use it

It does not return you a string that you can append to other strings (`intvw = intvw + newtext + difspace;...`), but rather an instance of the class `RichTextValue` that can be used as parameter only for determined methods. E.g. you can use it to assign formatted text to a range.

If your goal is to input certain cells of Column F into a cell, whereby cell "F1" is the question that should be bold and the rest of the cells are not formatted, you can do it by FIRST assigning incorporating the contents of `data[0][5]` into `intvw`to a cell, and SUBSEQUENTLY apply `newRichTextValue().build();` to `intvw`.

Hereby, the method [setTextStyle(startOffset, endOffset, textStyle)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value-builder) allows you apply the text style to `data[0][5]` only - provided that you know the position of this substring within the whole string.

If `data[0][5]` is the beginning of your string, the endOffset can be obtained simply through `data[0][5].length`.

Here is a modified version of your code that works:

```
function interview(alpha) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var interview = ss.getSheetByName("2020 Interview");
  var data = interview.getDataRange().getValues();
  var intvw = "";
  var bold = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setBold(true).build();
  var space = "\n\n";
  var difspace = "\n";
  var newtext = data[0][5]; 
  var endIndex=newtext.length;
  var month = ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", 'JUN', "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"];
  intvw = intvw + newtext + difspace;
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][0] == alpha){
      intvw = intvw + data[i][4] + " | " + data[i][1].getDate() + " " + month[data[i][1].getMonth()] + " " + data[i][1].getYear();
      intvw = intvw + space;
      intvw = intvw + data[i][5] + space;
   }
  }
 var newRichText = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
                              .setText(intvw)
                              .setTextStyle(0,endIndex,bold)
                              .build();
  //replace "A10" through the cell of your choice
  interview.getRange("A10").setRichTextValue(newRichText); 
}
```

If you wish to insert `data[0][5]` somewhere different than at the beginning of the string, or if you wish to insert several bold text ranges into a cell, you will have to find the respective `startOffset` and `endOffset`with Regex expressions.

Comment: That worked thank you! I don't think that I can use newRichTextValue() in a custom function in google sheets, but I will just make a trigger to run the function when the sheet is edited.

Comment: Yes, this is a good solution. Just be aware that onEdit trigger fire only if the edit has been taken place manually - not by a formula or script. See restrictions: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#Restrictions